# creating an object from strings

Tags: c#

i am extracting 4 strings from a text, then i want to create an object with attributes from them, using the first string as the object name and the rest as attributes  :

```
public void Load()
{
    string line = File.ReadAllText(path);
    foreach (var item in line)
    {
        string objectname = line.Split(':', '#')[1];
        string Name = line.Split('$', ':')[2];
        string Number = line.Split(':', '%')[3];
        string Addres = line.Split(':', '&')[4];

        StringBuilder StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    }
}
```

should i use `StringBuilder` for this? and how?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is for creating _strings_, so no. You need to look into serialization.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean set value of properties based on the dynamic data you can use reflection.

Assuming this is your class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And this is possible format of the text file:

```
Name=John$Address=Canada$Number=111
Number=333$Name=Bob$Address=
```

Then such code will iterate the lines and create instance of `Contact` for each, based on the values:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    string[] parts = line.Split('$');
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        string[] temp = part.split('=');
        string propName = temp[0];
        string propValue = (temp.Length > 1) ? temp[1] : "";
        contact.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(contact, propValue, null);
    }
}
```

Using this over the above sample two lines will create two instances with the given details.